# url rewrite using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite http://example.net/test/index.php/welcome/index to http://example.net/test/mainpage.html with .htaccess? I use below code but page not found error occurs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule [mainpage]?.html$ index.php/welcome/index [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got your ordering flipped :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule test/index.php/welcome/index  test/mainpage.html  [L]
```

Also, beware of the `[mainpage]?` because you've got it specified as a range (i.e. any one character 'm', 'a', 'i', etc. will match), and I think you meant to match the whole string.

Comment: thanks for your reply .I tried this code but still the error occours

Comment: Which directory is your `.htaccess` file in?  If your `.htaccess` is in the `test` directory, you'd need to pull the `test/` portion out of the `RewriteRule` and change `RewriteBase` to `/test`

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Process:
Just  Click on Wamp Icon.

```
WAMP>>

WAMP>>APACHE

WAMP>>APACHE>>httpd.conf
```

Open that file in notepad.Find Following code

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Rewrite that code in it by removing # symbol

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Thats Easy. Finally Save that file